# Why DbContext.Entry sets foreign key to null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

In my scenario, I have 2 entities `Estate` and `EstateCategory` where each `Estate` has a relation to an `EstateCategory` with a foreign key `CategoryId`. And in my repository I have this code to update entities:

```
//_dbSet is a DbSet<T>
public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
            if (entity == null)
            { throw new ArgumentNullException(); }

            var entry = _dbContext.Entry(entity);

             _dbSet.Attach(entity);

            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

My entities looks like this:

```
public class Estate {
    public int Id{set;get;}
    public string Title {set;get;}
    public decimal MeterPrice {set;get;}
    public int? CategoryId {set;get;}

    public virtual EstateCategory EstateCategory{set;get;}
}

public class EstateCategory{
        public int id{set;get;}
        public string Title{set;get;}
        public virtual ICollection<Estate> Estates{set;get;}

        public EstateCategory()
        {
             this.Estates = new HashSet<Estate>();
        } 
}
```

And in FluentApi mapping I wrote this code to create the relationship between `Estate` and `EstateCategory`:

```
public partial class Estate_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Estate>
{
        public Estate_Mapping()
        {  
        this.HasRequired(t => t.EstateCategory).WithMany(t => t.Estates).HasForeignKey(d => d.CategoryId);
}
}
```

When an `Estate` is passed to the `Update` method of repository, if `CategoryId` has a value (like 600) but `EstateCategory` is null, statement

```
var entry = _dbContext.Entry(entity)
```

automatically sets `CategoryId` to null.

And the database returns this exception:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CategoryId', table 'amlakdb3.dbo.Estates'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails

If I convert type of `CategoryId` of `Estate` from `int?` to `int`, then the `_dbSet.Attach(entity)` statement (from `Update` method in repository) throws an exception:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

And in presentation layer I have an copy of the `Estate` class that name is `EstateModel`. I have a function that can copy an object to another, which can copy an Entity Framework entity to a viewmodel. That's name is `simpleModelMapper`.

In mvc action my code to update an estate is:

```
public ActionResult EditEstate(EstateModel model)
{
    //EstateService is a repository 
    var _estate = EstateService.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == model.Id);

    if (_estate == null)
      {
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "can not find estate");
         return View(model)
       }

    Tools.simpleModelMapper(model, _estate,"Id");
      //Tools.simpleModelMapper syntax is:
      //Tools.simpleModelMapper(T sourceobj, T2 DestObj,"properties to ignor from mapping/copy")
try{
    EstateService.Update(_estate);

    EstateService.SaveChanges();//calls the DbContext savechange method
catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
```

If `_estate.CategoryId (model.CategoryId)` have older value this code throws above exceptions, but if `_estate.CategoryId (model.CategoryId)` takes new value it works good.

And I do not have any idea to this issue.